# Consuming an HTTP stream on google appengine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, http-streaming

I am trying to consume an http stream using GAE.

the logical flow is
{source1..N} --> [GAE] --> browser reporting & display

As I understand it, an HTTP stream will run forever, so a simple GET-process cycle won't work. Can anyone recommend an alternative approach that will work in the GAE model?

Comment: GAE only allows you to fetch urls via the [urlfetch](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview) api (no sockets etc...), and that has certain [limits](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/urlfetch/overview#Quotas_and_Limits), so I'm afraid consuming a stream won't be easy (or even possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what your requirement is but maybe you could look at the Channels API? So instead of having a continuous stream open, you could send updates from your app to a subscribing browser.

[Google App Engine - Channels API Overview](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/overview)